# I cannot send my users information to the database using mysqli_query

Tags: php, php-7

My code:

```
<?PHP

session_start();
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'Authentication';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
   $link, 
   $host, 
   $user, 
   $password, 
   $db,
   $port
);
if(isset($_POST['sbtn'])){
    session_start();
    $f_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['f_name']);
    $l_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['l_name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $c_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['c_pass']);

    if($pass == $c_pass){
        //create user
        $Password = md5($pass);
        mysqli_query($success, $db);

        $query = "INSERT INTO users( email, password, f_name, l_name) VALUES ($email, $pass, $f_name, $l_name)";
        mysqli_query($success, $query);
    }else{
        //tell user they are not equal
        echo("The two passwords did not match");
    }
}

mysqli_close($success);
?>
```

It seems to be that all of the rest of the code works as I have error checked the code and I am new to coding in php therefor I am struggling to understand how i am able to overcome this problem!

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are new to php, I suggest you to learn pdo rather than mysqli. This is not related to your problem but I still needed to say it.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the generated query to the screen and then execute it directly in mysql to see what is happening? (Hint: Quotes)

Answer (score -1):

Try to change:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users( email, password, f_name, l_name) VALUES ($email, $pass, $f_name, $l_name)";
```

to:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO users( email, `password`, f_name, l_name) VALUES ('$email', '$pass', '$f_name', '$l_name')";
```

**Explanation:**
[When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Then:

```
mysqli_query($success, $db);
mysqli_query($success, $query);
mysqli_close($success);
```

to:

```
mysqli_query($link, $db);
mysqli_query($link, $query);
mysqli_close($link);
```

And finally:

```
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump(mysqli_error_list($link));
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

(for debugging purposes)

**Explanation:**

*Sorry about my (poor) English*

All these replacements done ($success -> $link) because those functions requires  link identifier which returned by *mysqli_connect()* or *mysqli_init()*, but you passing *$success* (bool value)
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php    (Procedural style requirements)

Change:

```
$f_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['f_name']);
$l_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['l_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$c_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['c_pass']);
```

to

```
$f_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['f_name']);
$l_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['l_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['pass']);
$c_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['c_pass']);
```

**Explanation:**
*mysqli_real_escape_string* require link identifier returned by *mysqli_connect()* or mysqli_init().
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php (Procedural style requirements)

Comment: I would suggest adding some explanation as to how this would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks this worked but it fills up the database with empty information would you have any clue as to why it worked once changed and how i can fix it from sending across no information?

Comment: Added some explanation. Empty values problem was fixed by proper using  mysqli_real_escape_string() function  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php (Procedural style requirements)